# xcode mysql php error

Tags: php, iphone, mysql, ios, xcode

I'm sorry but this is my first question on here. I'm doing my school project of making an app and is having difficulties with the sql php connection.

It's posting blanks into the database.

I'm sorry for the format. I did not include the whole code, only the areas that I think affects my results.

Here's my code:

Booking.h

```
#define kPostURL @"http://XXX/app/quickbooking.php"
#define kFirstname @"firstname"
#define kLastname @"lastname"
#define kContactno @"contactno"
#define kEmail @"email"
#define kClub @"club"
#define kDatetime @"datetime"



@interface TellUs : UIViewController <UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIActionSheetDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate,UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate,UITextFieldDelegate, SKPSMTPMessageDelegate>{

IBOutlet UITextField *messageText;
IBOutlet UITextField *messageTextName;
IBOutlet UITextField *messageTextLastName;
IBOutlet UITextField *messageTextEmail;
IBOutlet UIButton *doneEditingButton;
IBOutlet UIButton *sendMail;
IBOutlet UILabel *feedbackMsg;
IBOutlet UIDatePicker *myDatePicker;
IBOutlet UITextField *yourTextField;
IBOutlet UIToolbar  *toolBar;
IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *barButton;
IBOutlet UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl;
IBOutlet UILabel *myDatePickerLabel;
IBOutlet UILabel *myPickerLabel;
IBOutlet UIPickerView *myPicker;
IBOutlet UITextField *yourTextFieldPicker;
IBOutlet UIButton *tellUsWhatYouThink;
NSArray *dataSource;
NSArray *fieldsArray;
CGFloat             animatedDistance;

IBOutlet UIButton *postBooking;
NSURLConnection *postConnection;


}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UITextField *messageText;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UITextField *messageTextName;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UITextField *messageTextLastName;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UITextField *messageTextEmail;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIButton *doneEditingButton;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIButton *sendMail;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UILabel *feedbackMsg;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIButton *tellUsWhatYouThink;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIDatePicker *myDatePicker;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UITextField *yourTextField;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UILabel *myDatePickerLabel;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UILabel *myPickerLabel;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIPickerView *myPicker;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *dataSource;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UITextField *yourTextFieldPicker;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextView *textView;

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIButton *postBooking;


-(void) postFirstname:(NSString *)firstname withLastname:(NSString *)lastname withContactno:(NSString *)contactno withEmail:(NSString *)email withClub:(NSString *)club withDatetime:(NSString *)datetime;


- (IBAction)postBooking:(id)sender;

@end
```

Booking.m

```
@synthesize feedbackMsg;
@synthesize tellUsWhatYouThink;
@synthesize sendMail;
@synthesize doneEditingButton;
@synthesize messageText;
@synthesize messageTextName;
@synthesize messageTextLastName;
@synthesize messageTextEmail;
@synthesize myDatePicker, yourTextField, segmentedControl;
@synthesize myDatePickerLabel;
@synthesize myPickerLabel, myPicker, dataSource;
@synthesize yourTextFieldPicker;
@synthesize textView;

@synthesize postBooking;

-(void) postFirstname:(NSString *)firstname withLastname:(NSString *)lastname withContactno:(NSString *)contactno withEmail:(NSString *)email withClub:(NSString *)club withDatetime:(NSString *)datetime {


if (firstname != nil && lastname != nil && contactno != nil
    && email != nil && club != nil && datetime != nil){

    NSMutableString *postString = [NSMutableString stringWithString:kPostURL];
    [postString appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"?%@=%@", kFirstname, firstname]];        
    [postString appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"&%@=%@", kLastname, lastname]];        
    [postString appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"&%@=%@", kContactno, contactno]];        
    [postString appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"&%@=%@", kEmail, email]];        
    [postString appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"&%@=%@", kClub, club]];        
    [postString appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"&%@=%@", kDatetime, datetime]];        
    [postString setString:[postString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:postString]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];        
    postConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self startImmediately:YES];

     }
}

-(IBAction)postBooking:(id)sender{

[self postFirstname: messageTextName.text withLastname: messageTextLastName.text withContactno: messageText.text withEmail: messageTextEmail.text withClub: myPickerLabel.text withDatetime: myDatePickerLabel.text];

[messageTextName resignFirstResponder];

messageTextName.text = nil;
messageTextLastName.text = nil;
messageText.text = nil;
messageTextEmail.text = nil;
myPickerLabel.text = nil;
myDatePickerLabel.text = nil;

[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

}

- (void)viewDidUnload {

}


- (void)dealloc {

[segmentedControl release];
[myDatePickerLabel release];
[myPickerLabel release];
[myPicker release];
[dataSource release];   
[super dealloc];
[sendMail release]; 
[messageText release];  
[doneEditingButton release];
[fieldsArray release];
[feedbackMsg release];
[tellUsWhatYouThink release];
[messageTextName release];
[messageTextLastName release];
[messageTextEmail release];
[yourTextField release];
[yourTextFieldPicker release];

[postBooking release];

}


@end
```

PHP file:

```
<?php 
session_start();
include("connectdb.php");
$first_name = $_GET['messageTextName'];
$last_name = $_GET['messageTextLastName'];
$contactno = $_GET['messageText'];
$email = $_GET['messageTextEmail'];
$club = $_GET['myPickerLabel'];
$date_time = $_GET['myDatePickerLabel'];
$query = "INSERT INTO booking VALUES ('', '$first_name', '$last_name', '$contactno', '$email', '$club', '$date_time')";
mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error("ERROR"));
mysql_close();
?>
```

Comment: It looks you are using old XCode... try to use newer one...@synthesize will not be required explicitly.

Comment: what is the first column - where you tray to write: '' ? I hope.. is not your index column (autoincrement)  or Primary key (A primary key column cannot contain NULL values); You can tray: "INSERT INTO booking (first_name, last_name, …) VALUES ('$first_name', '$last_name', ..)";

Comment: PS -  DO what @Spenser said

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In server side (PHP) you using `$_GET` global variable, but in `xcode` you set POST method

```
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
```

Change in php file

```
$_GET to $_POST or to $_REQUEST.
```